# Dealing with SQLServerPedia link-rot

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Last week [I posted a question on meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190451/dealing-with-sqlserverpedia-link-rot) about SQLServerPedia link rot. Essentially, all of the links we have here on dba.SE that point there are dead - they either go to a 404 page or the front page of their wiki. Most of the content isn't gone, but Dell/Quest did not do a very good job of revamping their site structure - they should have left in 404 handlers that were smart enough to redirect, but they didn't bother.

[The answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190466/165455) shows various ways to re-map the old links to the new locations of the content.

I have no idea who on SO is going to help hack away at these. But this is an official request for some assistance in updating the links in those posts *on our site* so that the links are valid and don't require any more work than clicking once. Who's with me?

The posts are here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22sqlserverpedia.com%22

Although Google might identify a few that our own search does not:

[Obnoxiously long Google link](https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=site%3adba.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+http%3A%2F%2Fsqlserverpedia.com%2F&oq=site%3adba.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+http%3A%2F%2Fsqlserverpedia.com%2F&gs_l=hp.12...1039.1039.0.2661.1.1.0.0.0.0.72.72.1.1.0....0.0..1c.2.20.psy-ab.cQnne1UH5xM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469%2Cd.dmg%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O&fp=30ae1b1e5770a225&biw=2468&bih=1344)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, thanks to the efforts of Martin Smith and a few others, we have completely eradicated this link-rot from our site. Now we can sit back and wait for <s>Quest</s> Dell to sell ToadWorld to someone else and do it all over again.